# Fully loop over a list with different starting index

Tags: python, list

So i have this list

```
station_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is an example, the real list could be longer, but always this pattern with increasing integers. As a part of my code, if some condition is fulfilled, i want to access that list at a different point than 1.
Let's say i want to start iterating at 2. How can i iterate over the list with a `for-loop` starting at 2, but still getting all elements exactly once?
So iteration order should be `2, 3, 4, 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
station_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
start = 1  # item = 2 is at index position 1!
for item in (station_list[start:] + station_list[:start]):
    # your code here
```

this outputs :

```
[2, 3, 4, 1]
```

You can learn more about slicing in python [here](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)

And if you want to have some extra information about lists in Python, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) might help.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: The only downside of slicing is that it returns a copy of a list. Another implementation with itertools can be done though.

Answer (score 4):

Easy way: construct a reordered list using two chunks from the original list:

```
station_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
start = 1
for i in station_list[start:] + station_list[:start]:
    print (i)
```

If you don't want to construct a reordered station list, you could use index wrapping instead:

```
station_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
start = 1
n = len(station_list)
for i in range(n):
    print (station_list[(i+start)%n])
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by simple collections.deque and then rotate with any index.

```
from collections import deque
d = deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
d.rotate(-1)
print (d)
```

Output:

```
deque([2, 3, 4, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
station_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
element_to_find = 2
start = station_list.index(element_to_find) - len(station_list)

for index in range(start, station_list.index(element_to_find)):
    print(station_list[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, define a seen list as where `# !` is at. (That is, after you define a list.)

```
int_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
seen = [] # {1}
```

Then, define your start.

```
start = 2
```

This is the loop part.

```
for n in range(start, list_length): # starts at position you desire...
    print(int_list[n])
    seen.append(int_list[n])
```

If you start at a position not equivalent to the start, this loops back again...

```
if int_list != seen: # if there are still some ints at start, go redo the loop until a seen int is found
    for x in range(0, list_length):
        print(int_list[x])
        seen.append(int_list[x])
        if int_list[x+1] in seen:
            break
```

The whole code:

```
int_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
seen = []

start = 2 

list_length = len(int_list)

for n in range(start, list_length): # starts at position you desire...
    print(int_list[n])
    seen.append(int_list[n])

if int_list != seen:
# if there are still some ints at start, go redo the 
#loop until a seen int is found
    for x in range(0, list_length):
        print(int_list[x])
        seen.append(int_list[x])
        if int_list[x+1] in seen:
            break
```

Not that compact, but it works.